# How to align embedded external svg file to the viewbox

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg, d3.js

[image]

I managed to insert an external svg file as "svg/xml", to my canvas. When I click the "download file" button, the file is loaded and is displayed, but I am not able to align it correctly to be inside the view box.  It displays at the lower left corner outside the view box.  I am not able to figure out the alignment issue.  I want to display the "title" centered at the top before the root node.

```js
var treeData = [{
  "name": "Top Level",
  "parent": "null",
  "remark": "yes",
  "children": [{
      "name": "Level 2: A",
      "parent": "Top Level",
      "remark": "yes",
      "children": [{
          "name": "Son of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A",
          "remark": "null"
        },
        {
          "name": "Daughter of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A",
          "remark": "null"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Level 2: B",
      "parent": "Top Level",
      "remark": "null"
    }
  ]
}];

//*************************************************************************************
// 1. Create the button
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "download file";
//*************************************************************************************

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
  rectW = 100,
  rectH = 30,
  duration = 750,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

//swap x and y for vertical
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH / 2];
    //  .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });
  });

var svgBgImg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image');
svgBgImg.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '100%');
svgBgImg.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '100%');
svgBgImg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', 'http://localhost/images/background-F4EED7.svg');
svgBgImg.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', '0');
svgBgImg.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', '0');
svgBgImg.setAttributeNS(null, 'visibility', 'visible');

//var gElement = document.createElement('svg:g');
var gElement = document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, 'g');
gElement.setAttribute("id", "fg");
console.log(gElement);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append(function() {
    return gElement;
  }) //The argument to .append() has to be a function, you can't just pass element to it.
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  //swap x and y for vertical
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("rect")
    //nodeEnter.append("circle")
    //  .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Filter to put tooltip only on nodes that have information associated with it
  var nodesWithInfo = nodeEnter.filter(function(d) {
    return (d.remark != 'null')
  })
  nodesWithInfo
    .append("circle")
    .attr("export-ignore", true)
    .attr("cx", 96)
    .attr("cy", 7)
    .attr("r", 10);

  nodesWithInfo
    .append("text")
    .attr("export-ignore", true)
    .attr("id", "infoText")
    .attr("x", 96)
    .attr("y", 7)
    .attr("dy", ".30em")
    .style("font-style", "italic")
    .style("font-family", "serif")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .text("i");

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  //swap x and y for vertical layout
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

  //nodeUpdate.select("circle")
  nodeUpdate.select("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .style("stroke", "black")
    //  .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .attr("x", rectW / 2)
    .attr("y", rectH / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  //vertical switch x and y positions
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  //nodeExit.select("circle")
  nodeExit.select("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .style("stroke", "black");
  //  .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

//*************************************************************************************
// 2. Append button somewhere
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(button)
  .setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + 0 + ")");

//*************************************************************************************

function svgDataURL(svg) {
  var svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
  var dataURL = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svgAsXML);
  return dataURL;
}

button.onclick = function() {
  var groupElement = document.getElementById('fg');

  const bb = groupElement.getBBox();

  //load the title image
  var titlePosX = bb.width / 6 + bb.x + 25; //added offeset of 25 to align to center as much as possible
  var imageWidth = bb.width / 4;
  var imageHeight = imageWidth * .33;

  var newVboxH = bb.height + imageHeight + 10;

  console.log('newVboxH ', newVboxH);
  console.log('titlePosX ' + titlePosX + ' imageHeight ', +imageHeight + ' imageWidth ' + imageWidth);

  groupElement.setAttribute("transform", "translate(0," + (imageHeight + 10) + ")scale(.995,.995)"); //scale down by .05% to fit nicely

  svg.attr('viewBox', ' ' + bb.x + ' ' + bb.y + '  ' + bb.width + ' ' + newVboxH);
  svg.attr("width", "100%");
  svg.attr("height", "100%");
  svg.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");

  //how to put the border around the cloned SVG element
  var borderRect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
  borderRect.setAttribute("id", "bRect");
  borderRect.setAttribute("width", bb.width);
  borderRect.setAttribute("height", newVboxH);
  borderRect.setAttribute("x", bb.x);
  borderRect.setAttribute("y", bb.y);
  borderRect.setAttribute("style", "fill:blue;stroke:pink;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:0.1;stroke-opacity:0.9");

  d3.xml("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/SVG_logo_h.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function(error, xml) {
    if (error) throw error;
    xml.documentElement.setAttribute("transform", "translate(0,0)scale(.995,.995)");
    xml.documentElement.setAttribute("transform", "translate(0," + (imageHeight + 10) + ")scale(.995,.995)"); //scale down by .05% to fit nicely
    xml.documentElement.setAttribute('width', imageWidth);

    groupElement.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
    groupElement.appendChild(borderRect);

    // bring back to original position
    groupElement.setAttribute("transform", 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')scale(.7)');
  });
};
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  /*
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Tree Example</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Please try and find some placeholder SVG online to replace the one in your code, so it looks as much as possible like your local environment. We don't have access to your localhost, so any image off the internet should work, as long as the behaviour is the same

Comment: @RubenHelsloot put in svg via a URL link.  Thanks for the suggestion on how to insert a SVG.

Comment: You never replaced the file url in your code snippet

Comment: @RubenHelsloot I did, I replaced it with "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/SVG_logo_h.svg". if you click the "download file" button, the program displays the behavior I am describing

Comment: Ah I got confused by the line `svgBgImg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', 'http://localhost/images/background-F4EED7.svg');` in your code